# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path

Tags: java, android, logcat, splash-screen

after launching my app, emulator tells me that unfortunatelly it had stopped. I had the same error previously, then I fixed it but after adding splash activity i have this problem again.

```
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Process: com.gosha.bux, PID: 857
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gosha.bux/com.gosha.bux.perv}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gosha.bux.perv" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gosha.bux-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.gosha.bux-2, /system/lib]]
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.gosha.bux.perv" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gosha.bux-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.gosha.bux-2, /system/lib]]
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
03-24 15:14:21.180: E/AndroidRuntime(857):  ... 11 more
03-24 15:14:43.061: I/Process(857): Sending signal. PID: 857 SIG: 9
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.gosha.bux"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:debuggable="true"
    >
    <activity
        android:name="com.gosha.bux.perv"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.gosha.bux.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.gosha.bux.MAINACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

splash activity

```
    public class perv extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.gosha.bux.R.layout.pervy);
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                finally {
                    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.gosha.bux.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openMainActivity);
                }
            }

        };
    }

    }
```

Comment: you are doing mistake in package name or not making entry of target activity in manifest.xml

Comment: clean ur application / project

Comment: Did you got a answer for this? As now I am also facing the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getapplicationcontext(),
                            TARGET_Activity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

and in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name="com.your.packagename.TARGET_Activity"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your depends compile:

```
'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

and set `multiDexEnabled true`.

In `YourApplication`: `extends MultiDexApplication`

add this:

```
@Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Finally in `AndroidManifest` declare: `android:name=".MyApplication"`

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.gosha.bux.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openMainActivity);
```

is wrong, instead use:

```
Intent openMainActivity = new Intent(this, YourMainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Public class perv you wrote this:

setContentView(com.gosha.bux.R.layout.pervy);

You wrote pervy, instead of perv and this will possibly cause this error